# Matplotlib can't find Numpy on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph, raspberry-pi

I have been trying to use matplotlib to graph some data for a project I am working on. The code I am using works fine on my laptop, but not on a Raspberry Pi. Anytime say

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cillian-toole-btyse-project/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/home/cillian-toole-btyse-project/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/home/cillian-toole-btyse-project/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 8, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cillian-toole-btyse-project/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "/home/cillian-toole-btyse-project/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__config__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
  File "/home/cillian-toole-btyse-project/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "/usr/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.26.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cillian-toole-btyse-project/Desktop/analysis.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/home/cillian-toole-btyse-project/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 156, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/home/cillian-toole-btyse-project/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg) from e
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
```

I have tried to delete and reinstall numpy and matplotlib but to no avail. I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B+

The error occurs regardless of whatever code I have written. Even if I just have the line

'''
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
'''

in a script it still gives the error.

Comment: You've left out a lot of important information. Such as exactly how you installed `numpy` and `matplotlib`. Also, does running `find / -name 'libopenblas.so*'` find any instances of that shared library? Does the documentation for however you installed `numpy` and `matplotlib` state that following those instructions will also install the `libopenblas` shared library? Or do those instructions tell you to install that library separately?

Comment: @KurtisRader Thanks, I installed numpy and matplotlib using pip install. I tried looking for libopenblas but I got a permission denied error. I also tried sudo find / -name 'libopenblas.so*'. The error also appears when importing numpy.